# Convert a JSP contained in a String to a Servlet programatically

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a JSP in a string variable in a servlet and I would like to compile it as a JSP myself (on the fly, programatically).  Right now what I am doing is saving the string to a file and accessing that file (which generates the resulting servlet) - something like:

```
// and He created JSP from mere html code
final String jsp = convertToJSP(someHTML);
// create a jsp file with the above
final File jspFile = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/"), jspFilename);
// write it to a file FIXME: This must be expensive, the user is waiting
// I DONT WANT TO WRITE THIS TO FILE: GENERATE SERVLET IMMEDIATELY FROM CODE
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(jspFile, jsp, "UTF-8");
// access that jsp
resp.sendRedirect(jspFilename);
```

This is obviously expensive and requires an IO operation.  Any ideas/suggestions on how to do this ?

I understand that I'll have to use/tie down to tomcat jasper (jspc) at some point and I am fine with that (Tomcat is my servlet container).

Many Thanks,
JP

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the [Jasper2 JSP Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat#Jasper) - this is how Tomcat translates JSPs to servlets.

Comment: Yes I figured as much out - but I couldn't find any Java code which does it.  Its all Ant tasks which call JspC, Compiler, ADTCompiler classes - which themselves are a nightmare to follow.  

I was wondering if anyone has done this sort of thing before, and if therefore some code, more specific pointers could be supplied.

Comment: look through the API for the Jasper compiler - it might be easy to get started.